# What supplies to bring to a beer festival?

Tags: equipment

At the risk of being flagged off-topic, as this is a bit tangential to actual brewing and fermentation...

It's Spring, and the beer festival season isn't exactly in "full-swing" yet, but I don't know too many homebrewers who don't try to attend at least a couple of festivals over the course of a year.  They're a great way to get some inspiration for future batches, to meet other people interested in the hobby, and to just try out all sorts of beer that you might not have tried otherwise.

From camp furniture to your favorite snifter, what do you consider "essential equipment" to take with you to a beer festival?

Answer (score 3):

Emergency contact information.